# Grails app as an iframe

Tags: web-applications, grails, iframe, integration

I am building a Grails app to be integrated in an existing web app.

I need to provide some new functionality, offering a user login.
Ideally, I'd like to provide this functionality within an iFrame (or similar containers), so that the user can login/interact with data/logout from a single static page embedded in the existing web app, without changing anything in the web app.

How would you go about to do that?

Thanks,

Mulone

Comment: Not sure where the problem should be by just using an iFrame..